# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0: Is there any hard limit for the length of value for PutState function

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

For example in redis, a String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length. Is there something like that for hyperledger fabric. My thought is it should be limited by the transaction size or block size, but I cannot find the exact number anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `PutState` function is bounded by overall gRPC maximum message size which currently configured to 100Mb, you can find how it being configured [server.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d9c320297bd2a4eff2eb253ce84dc431ef860972/core/comm/server.go#L170)

```
// set max send and recv msg sizes
serverOpts = append(serverOpts, grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(MaxSendMsgSize()))
serverOpts = append(serverOpts, grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(MaxRecvMsgSize()))
```

and default value could be denoted [config.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d9c320297bd2a4eff2eb253ce84dc431ef860972/core/comm/config.go#L23).

```
// Max send and receive bytes for grpc clients and servers
maxRecvMsgSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024
maxSendMsgSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024
```